# How to Download PDF files from Netsuite File Cabinet to Local drive without any click?

Tags: javascript, cmd, netsuite, suitescript

> I have one script customization, which creates multiple PDF files on daily basis and store it in File Cabinet.
>
> Now i need to download all new created PDF files on daily basis.
>
> I can download PDF by click on download button. Is there any idea or script to download all PDF files on my local drive at a time ?

Answer (score 1):

Put each batch in its own folder.

Navigate to the parent folder

click the batch folder's download link. You'll get a zipped file of the folder's contents

Answer (score 0):

If you have an sftp server you can build a scheduled SuiteScript 2.0 map/reduce script to push all the files to a specific folder on this server and then process them as you need.

If you want to push all of those files to your a folder on you local pc, it's not possible via script.